# How to print to the Debug Area with Swift UI in Xcode 13?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want my `print` message to be shown in the Debug Area in Xcode 13. There are several questions like this on StackOverflow, some of them suggest using the `Debug Mode`, which seems to have been removed in Xcode 13.

Here is my `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("button", action: {
            print("abc")
        })
    }
}
```

Though I use `print("abc")`, when I click the button, there's nothing in the Debug Area. How to show it?

[image: Debug Area]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not running the app. You're just looking at the preview. Press Command-R and run the app in a simulator; tap the button in the simulator.

Note that when you're actually running the app, the debug bar (at the top of the debug area) looks quite different:

[image]

Comment: OMG, that is really true. So I was just looking at the preview? Then what does it mean to click the "play" button (▶) on the top of the preview phone? I was doing that previously. When I do that, the phone seems to be running, I can click my button, it will do what the action specifies, except `print` doesn't work.

Comment: Running the preview imitates the app, which is amazing and convenient, but you're not actually debugging so no output comes to the debugging console. Previewing has its uses for sure, but running is the real deal.